# Не удается установить kivy в pycharm

Tags: python, kivy, pycharm

По какой то непонятной причине не могу установить kivy да и все другие библиотеки тоже не получается, не знаю в чем может быть проблема.

Создаю новый проект.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем устанавливаю в терминале kivy(pip install kivy) и терминал мне пишет, что все уже установлено.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но при этом всем проект все равно жалуется, что нет модуля kivy.
Я пробую установить модуль при наведении мышью на import kivy, но когда начинается установка в нижнем правом углу экрана, она просто напросто бесконечная и никак не продвигается сколько бы я не ждал.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять в чем может быть проблема.
Уже пробовал пересоздавать проекты, но результат один и тот же.

Comment: При создании проекта вы указали интерпритатор 3.10 а pip устанавливает пакеты для 3.9

Comment: Благодарю, так и думал, что проблема какая то очевидная окажется....